# Figures and Tables in ToC within section

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

I have to fulfill a layout requirement, where the ToC includes a list of figures and a list of tables (that's OK), but additionally in the pdf bookmarks each figure and table should be indicated within the section where it appears. Take the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{
linktocpage=true,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=blue,      
urlcolor=blue,
bookmarksopen=true
}
\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\title{\begin{center}
My Title
\end{center}
} 
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\setcounter{page}{2}

\newpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage
\section{My first section}

Bla, bla bla.

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My first Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My first Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage
\section{My second section}

More bla, bla.

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My second Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My second Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It generates this ToC, which is exactly what I need:

[image]

But it also generates these pdf bookmarks:

[image]

But I need the pdf bookmarks to look like this (sorry for using Code style):

```
Contents
|- 1 My first Section
   |- My first figure
   |- My first table 
|- 2 My second Section
   |- My second figure
   |- My second table
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The `ToC` does not really include the `LoF` etc. They are just on the same page (due to short real contents)

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the welcome. I'm aware of that, actually it would be better to have the LoF and LoT within the ToC below the sections, but that's not an acceptance criterion for the layout (I have to match some authorities-defined layout). Critical is the bookmark question. ... May be I should add that i have hundreds of tables and figures automatically generated from R with knitr. So manually setting pdfbookmark and the level is not a real option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to hook into `\caption` and add the bookmark with a unique bookmark label (generated by the total number of figures or tables)

To get the total numbers use (well, my ;-)) package `xassocnt` and associate stepping the relevant counters with them.

The `\pdfbookmark[2]{text}{label:name}` will add the figure or table entry as subsection level to the current section.

Be careful to use `\texorpdfstring{tex content}{pdf content}` for specific content of the caption, i.e. `\caption{\texorpdfstring{$E=mc^2}{E=mc\textsuperscript{2}}}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\newcounter{totalfigure}
\newcounter{totaltable}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigure}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltable}


\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}




\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\caption@@caption\caption
\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \caption@@caption{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \caption@@caption[#2]{#3}%
      \pdfbookmark[2]{#2}{\@captype:\number\value{total\@cap@type}}%
    }{%
      \phantomsection
      \caption@@caption{#3}%
      \pdfbookmark[2]{#3}{\@captype:\number\value{total\@captype}}%
    }%
  }%
}
}


\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{
  linktocpage=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,      
  urlcolor=blue,
  bookmarksopen=true
}

%\captionsetup[figure]{format=bookmarksfig}
%\captionsetup[table]{format=bookmarkstab}


\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\title{\begin{center}
    My Title
\end{center}
} 
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\setcounter{page}{2}

\newpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage
\section{My first section}

Bla, bla bla.

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My first Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My first Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage
\section{My second section}

More bla, bla.

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My second Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My second Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

This does not use `xassoccnt` but a simple check of `\@captype` and increases the relevant `\total...` counter then.

It uses `\currentpdfbookmark` which takes care of the section level.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcounter{totalfigure}
\newcounter{totaltable}

%\usepackage{xassoccnt}
%\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigure}
%\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltable}


\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{xparse}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\caption@@caption\caption


\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{som}{%
  %checking which caption type is here and stepping the relevant total counter
  \def\temp@@a{figure}
  \def\temp@@b{table}
  \ifx\@captype\temp@@a 
  \stepcounter{total\@captype}%
  \fi
  \ifx\@captype\temp@@b 
  \stepcounter{total\@captype}%
  \fi
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \caption@@caption{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \phantomsection
      \caption@@caption[#2]{#3}%
      \currentpdfbookmark{#2}{\@captype:\number\value{total\@cap@type}}%
    }{%
      \phantomsection
      \caption@@caption{#3}%
      \currentpdfbookmark{#3}{\@captype:\number\value{total\@captype}}%
    }%
  }%
}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{
  linktocpage=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,      
  urlcolor=blue,
  bookmarksopen=true
}



\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\title{%
  \begin{center}
    My Title
  \end{center}
} 
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\setcounter{page}{2}%

\newpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage
\section{My first section}

Bla, bla bla.

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My first Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My first Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage
\section{My second section}

More bla, bla.

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My second Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My second Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Foo subsection}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My third Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My third Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}


\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}


\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My fourth Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My fourth Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage

\section{Yet another section}



\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My sixth Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My sixth Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Foo subsection}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My seventh Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My seventh Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}


\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}


\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My eighth Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My eighth Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

**Next update: With figure etc. numbers**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcounter{totalfigure}
\newcounter{totaltable}

%\usepackage{xassoccnt}
%\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigure}
%\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltable}


\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{xparse}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\caption@@caption\caption

\newcommand{\generatebookmark}[1]{%
  \belowpdfbookmark{\csname \@captype name\endcsname\ \csname the\@captype\endcsname: #1}{\@captype:\number\value{total\@captype}}%
}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{som}{%
  %checking which caption type is here and stepping the relevant total counter
  \def\temp@@a{figure}
  \def\temp@@b{table}
  \ifx\@captype\temp@@a 
  \stepcounter{total\@captype}%
  \fi
  \ifx\@captype\temp@@b 
  \stepcounter{total\@captype}%
  \fi
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \caption@@caption{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \phantomsection
      \caption@@caption[#2]{#3}%
      \generatebookmark{#2}%
    }{%
      \phantomsection
      \caption@@caption{#3}%
      \generatebookmark{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{
  linktocpage=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,      
  urlcolor=blue,
  bookmarksopen=true
}



\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\title{%
  \begin{center}
    My Title
  \end{center}
} 
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\setcounter{page}{2}%

\newpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage
\section{My first section}

Bla, bla bla.

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My first Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My first Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage
\section{My second section}

More bla, bla.

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My second Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My second Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Foo subsection}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My third Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My third Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}


\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}


\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My fourth Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My fourth Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage

\section{Yet another section}



\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My sixth Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My sixth Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Foo subsection}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My seventh Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My seventh Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}


\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}


\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My eighth Figure}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{My eighth Table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end {tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Christian, thanks for your answer. I wasn't able to get your MWE running. `! LaTeX Error: File xassoccnt.sty not found`. Could you please guide me on how to install your package?  That said, I have some doubts on how universal this will be. My MWE had just 2 main sections, my real case has sections and subsections, It will be difficult to introduce the bookmark level manually (there will be levels 2, 3, 4), am I right?

Comment: Installation of packages depends on your TeX distribution. I think, I can add a solution without `xassoccnt`. Do you really want to use figures/table in the relevant section level? Try `\currentpdfbookmark` instead of `pdfbookmark[2]` (the remaining arguments are the same then)

Comment: I didn't know `\currentpdfbookmark` , that can easily solve the problem indeed. If you could help me getting your package running or implementing a workaround you would save my day! (I'm using MikTeX 2.9). I'll try in parallel anyway. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @albifrons: I am working on it ;-)

Comment: @albifrons: See the update at the end of the post

Comment: it's working now. Almost perfect. I changed `\currentpdfbookmark` by `\belowpdfbookmark` and now it does what it is supposed to. The figure and table numbers are missing yet, but I guess I will be able to solve that by myself. I'm afraid I owe you a lunch :)

Comment: @albifrons: That's because `\....bookmark` does not write them automatically. Use `\csname the\@captype\endcsname`.

Comment: @albifrons: Now you owe my two lunches ;-) See the next update, please ;-)

Comment: you're my hero!

Comment: @albifrons: :D :D Happy TeXing!

Comment: I'm putting this in the comments instead of a new question with a new MWE, because it depends directly on the fix proposed above by Christian Hupfer. The fix works fine with knitr using `xtable` ... as long as the `tabular.environment` is not `longtable`. In these cases, the bookmark is missing. I have no clue why.

Comment: @albifrons: Most likely because `table` uses another setup for `\caption`. You can't expect unusual requests to work with any package

Comment: The longtable and the caption generated in the TeX file look pretty standard:
`\begin{longtable}{llll}
\caption{My caption}
...`

I also changed the code you proposed above to include:
`...
 \def\temp@@c{longtable}
...
 \ifx\@captype\temp@@c 
   \stepcounter{totaltable}
 \fi
`
Do you think it'd be better to send a new question with a new MWE?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer help me please with my question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476682/not-appear-because-in-the-bookmark

Comment: @x-rw: Comments are not meant to lead away to request help for other posts. You've got an answer there, already.